# data types and structures in functional programming and associated behaviours

Tags: types, functional-programming

After much reading on functional programming and lambda calculus I am still lost as to how to associate behaviour with data types and structures. I am guessing I am still in the wrong mindset.

Apart from the identity function, I would have thought that every other arithmetic operation depends on rules specific to the value types or structure.

For example, Matrices, Vectors, Scalar, Random Number Distribution and Imaginary numbers all have their own associative, commutative and and arithmetic rules.

How are types and or behaviours attached to values and/or operators?

Comment: There is no general solution that applies to all of functional programming. Every language can do it on its own. Either you use overloading of operators, or indeed use different operators for every type.

Comment: The answers received (1. Depends, 2. Take a full course, 3. Read a book) suggests that this is a bad question, or at least not well formulated. Should i just delete this question?

Comment: My thinking was if a value is locked in a monad how do i know how to compose and or operate if i don't get to check the value. I understand i am thinking about it the wrong way and i thought i was not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

As in any other programming language, that is developing suitable libraries.
Consider for instance a very basic calculus, like the calculus of inductive constructors (CIC), that is no too far from a (typed) lambda calculus. 
CIC is the core of the Coq proof system: everything is written is this basic calculus, and still you may write complex programs on all the datatypes you mentioned (and reason about them). 
One crucial point that helps to understand lambda calculus is the so called Bohm-Berarducci encoding of inductive types ([automatic synthesis of type lambda programs on term algebras](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0304397585901355/1-s2.0-0304397585901355-main.pdf?_tid=6659d004-3255-11e7-8607-00000aacb362&acdnat=1494072982_c44cda9c9c2daff274dad9936148ed95)), that provides the main techniques to work on integers, records, lists, trees, and so on. The rest is easy.

Comment: Thank for pointer. Unfortunately, I tried to check Bohm-Berarducci and I am completely lost. It is to me as if the jargon and notation conventions are such that the explanations are only accessible to those who already know the answer. Is there an implementation somewhere in code (or in english)?

Comment: @Hurelu I added a reference. For Coq, there is the excellent book "Interactive theorem proving and program development" by Bertot and Casteran.

Comment: @Hurelu The key intuition is that you code an object c of an inductive type with the function implementing the traversal of the datatype pre-instantiated on c. But the details would require a small introductory course.